# Magento Customer Custom Attributes import error

Tags: php, magento

`Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` on line 336 ->

```
public function getAttributes()

    {
        if ($this->_attributes === null) {
          $this->_attributes = $this->_getResource()
          ->loadAllAttributes($this)
          ->getSortedAttributes();
        }
       Mage::log($this->_attributes);
       return $this->_attributes;
    }
```

When I try to retrieve my customer attributes my custom attributes are missing.
The result $this->_attributes

```
[warning] => Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute Object
    (...
    )
[credit_limit] => Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute Object
    (...
    )
```

The above is my custom attributes warning and credit_limit works fine, but the member_id array which I have recently added is missing. Am I missing something here? FYI I'm using an extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manage-customer-attributes.html to manage customer attribute. 
[image]

Comment: Are they all the same type, same configuration and set up the same way? It's hard to know why this one might not work when the others do. Can you retrieve it via `Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load(idhere)->getMemberId()`?

Comment: @RobbieAverill they are set in the same way and Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load(idhere)->getMemberId() return the correct value which is A123. I can edit everything in the admin and it works perfectly, but when i try to import those value through csv it doesnt work.

Comment: fyi when i tried to log $this->_attributes['member_id'], it says undefined index 

     Notice: Undefined index: member_id  in /home/weststar/public_html/webstore/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php on line 357

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem lies when I forgot to add the attributes to group.

```
$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
   $entityTypeId,
   $attributeSetId,
   $attributeGroupId,
   'member_id',
   '100' );

$oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer','member_id');
$oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer')); 
$oAttribute->save();

$setup->endSetup();
```